# Get Username of Friends List

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to migrate my app to API V2.0 and I can't find how to get certain fields of a friend of the current user.

On my other version I made:

```
SELECT uid,username,birthday_date,name,first_name,last_name,current_location,profile_url FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

But this fields don't appear on the 2.0 API??

How can I bring them in? Always asking for permission. Maybe adding permissions on the app settings?

Answer (score 2):

> /me/username is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Btw, FQL is deprecated and not available in v2.1+ anymore and friend permissions are gone since v2.0 so you can't get birthdays of friends who did not authorize your App too. Better use `/me/friends` to get friends - only those who authorized your App, of course.

Comment: I wonder how many friend's birthday reminder apps are out there... :-/